# Apply complicated IF formula on column

Tags: google-sheets

How to apply the following formula onto column without dragging it:

```
=IF(J:J = "", "", SUMIFS(D:D, B:B, J:J, C:C, "In") - SUMIFS(D:D, B:B, J:J, C:C, "Out"))
```

Comment: Unfortunately although SUMIF works with array formulas SUMIFS doesn't so no easy answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But as a workaround you should be able to combine the conditions in a SUMIF like this

```
=ArrayFormula(if(J:J="","",sumif(B:B&C:C,J:J&"In",D:D)-sumif(B:B&C:C,J:J&"Out",D:D)))
```

Comment: It works!!! I had to shorten the ranges because it was calculating for ages and it was giving me the error, something about to enter more rows.

=ArrayFormula(if(J2:J2000="","",sumif(B2:B2000&C2:C2000,J2:J2000&"In",D2:D2000)-sumif(B2:B2000&C2:C2000,J2:J2000&"Out",D2:D2000)))

Thanks a lot. Excellent solution.